# Why the density function of Bernoulli trials where x is assumed from a beta distribution is the product of the binomial and the beta pdf?

Tags: probability, beta-function

I am trying to self-learning probabilities using the excellent [Grinstead & Snell "Introduction to Probability"](https://github.com/sylvaticus/IntroductionToProbability/tree/master/book) (that is also open source).

I am stuck on Example 4.23, that involves a Bernoulli trials where the probability $x$ of $i$ successes is assumed arising from a Beta distribution.

The book firstly defines $m(i|x) = b(n,x,i)$ as the binomial distribution with probability $x$ for success given the value of $x$.

It then explains that, given x is chosen at random from [0,1] with a beta density $B(\alpha,\beta,x)$, the density function for the outcome of the pair $(x,i)$ is

$$f(x,i) = m(i|x) * B(\alpha,\beta,x)$$

My question is: why the two functions are multiplied ? The two events (rising $x$ and $i$) are not surely independent..
In particular why $x$ is not just substituted with its expected value, that [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) I read being $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$i.e. 
$$m(i|x) = b(n,x,i) = b(n,E[B(\alpha,\beta,x)],i) = b(n,\frac{\alpha} {\alpha + \beta},i)$$
?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got it.. it doesn't matter if they are independent or not.. $f(x,i)$ is $P(i \cap x)$ and hence, in general, equal to $P(i | x) * P(x)$

Comment: Bernoulli is a name. Big B.

Comment: This fact is used in Bayesian statistics: 'B' is a beta prior distribution on the success probability, 'm' is a binomial PDF viewed as a likelihood function for the success probability given observed data and 'f' is the posterior distribution of the success probability. You are probably not ready for this now, but file it away in the deep recesses of memory for use later. // I'm a great fan of G &S; hope you continue to enjoy it.